# Reversing light-dark colors for fa-comments or other icons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Im new to font-awesome, but ive been aware of it for a while now, but I must say that its...awesome!

Im looking at a bootstrap template to use with a project and one of the icons is fa-comments, but its white on a dark background, unlike the default which is dark on white.  What controls the colors?

template (white on dark)
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html

font-awesome link (notice the dark on white)
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/comments/

The html that contains that large (fa-5x) comments icon is this:

```
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge">26</div>
                                    <div>New Comments!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS `color` property will change the color. Font Awesome is just a font of special characters. Use it like any other font.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/

> If you change the font-size of the icon's container, the icon gets
>   bigger. Same things goes for color, drop shadow, and anything else
>   that gets inherited using CSS.